# Can't see my device in Droid Explorer

Tags: droid-explorer

But my device still could be seen in `adb devices`, it said 
`List of devices attached
DU2TAN1581059861        device`

I've turned on usb debugging and MTP mode on my android.

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: Try this : http://visualgdb.com/adbfix/

Comment: @AnuragThakur I've fixed that message, still can't see.

Comment: what exactly you can't see?

Comment: I posted the screenshot on, can't see anything but three buttons.

Comment: Can you execute any commands from ADB shell like reboot? Also please give more information about the device that you are using

Comment: @AnuragThakur Yes I can.

Comment: What happens if you click on 'i don't see my device'

Comment: @AnuragThakur It pointed to a web page, a tutorial for how to turn usb debugging on.

Comment: Well, I guess I will have to try it out myself, but I can only test it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

The format of the info returned by the

> adb devices -l

Appears to have changed. So the regular expression extracting the info doesn't work any more.

I have worked out a new one, but haven't worked out how to submit the change into the github repo.